# Access a website globally which is running nicely in LAN

Tags: silverlight, iis, lan

I have developed an application (website) which is running in LAN nicely.

My application is built using Silverlight and I have published that website in IIS and I can access that application nicely in LAN through following LINK.

`http://192.168.137.24/SilverLightBusinessApplicationWeb/SilverLightBusinessApplicationTestPage.html#/Home`

Now I require to access that application globally all over the word from any PC through INTERNET so for that, what configuration I have to use?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to redirect your port 80 to LAN IP via router/modem settings.

Comment: sithereal,,,,, what should be the change in LINK and what should be the configuration in server?? Thank you so much for answering....

Comment: your new link will be: http://your.global.ip.address/SilverLightBusinessApplicationWeb/SilverLightBusinessApplicationTestPage.html#/Home (you can learn your external ip from whatismyip.com). You don't need to change anything in the server. Just forward your port 80 to 192.168.137.24 (your LAN ip)